# Table with multiple incrementing columns which doesn't reuse deleted column values

Tags: mysql

I wish to have a MySQL InnoDB table with an auto-incrementing primary key which also has a column which increments independently based on the type of record.

For instance, my records might be as shown below (shown as two tables to highlight the two incrementing columns).

If a record at the end of the sub-incrementing series is deleted such as PK 12, and then a record is inserted for that same type, the SecondaryKey should not be duplicated, and the new record should have PK 17 and SecondaryKey 5 (and not 4).

How is this best accomplished?

```
+----+------+--------------+----------------+
| PK | Type | SecondaryKey |      Data      |
+----+------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 | a    |            1 | Data for PK 1  |
|  2 | a    |            2 | Data for PK 2  |
|  3 | c    |            1 | Data for PK 3  |
|  4 | d    |            1 | Data for PK 4  |
|  5 | a    |            3 | Data for PK 5  |
|  6 | b    |            1 | Data for PK 6  |
|  7 | c    |            2 | Data for PK 7  |
|  8 | a    |            4 | Data for PK 8  |
|  9 | d    |            2 | Data for PK 9  |
| 10 | b    |            2 | Data for PK 10 |
| 11 | d    |            3 | Data for PK 11 |
| 12 | d    |            4 | Data for PK 12 |
| 13 | a    |            5 | Data for PK 13 |
| 14 | b    |            3 | Data for PK 14 |
| 15 | b    |            4 | Data for PK 15 |
| 16 | c    |            3 | Data for PK 16 |
+----+------+--------------+----------------+

+----+------+--------------+----------------+
| PK | Type | SecondaryKey |      Data      |
+----+------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 | a    |            1 | Data for PK 1  |
|  2 | a    |            2 | Data for PK 2  |
|  5 | a    |            3 | Data for PK 5  |
|  8 | a    |            4 | Data for PK 8  |
| 13 | a    |            5 | Data for PK 13 |
|  6 | b    |            1 | Data for PK 6  |
| 10 | b    |            2 | Data for PK 10 |
| 14 | b    |            3 | Data for PK 14 |
| 15 | b    |            4 | Data for PK 15 |
|  3 | c    |            1 | Data for PK 3  |
|  7 | c    |            2 | Data for PK 7  |
| 16 | c    |            3 | Data for PK 16 |
|  4 | d    |            1 | Data for PK 4  |
|  9 | d    |            2 | Data for PK 9  |
| 11 | d    |            3 | Data for PK 11 |
| 12 | d    |            4 | Data for PK 12 |
+----+------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Why you want to make like this

Comment: What if you ever want to delete a row. Should the sequence for that type be adjusted?

Comment: MyISAM can do this, but InnoDB can't.

Comment: You can do this with [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  As described above, don't wish to reuse the ID.

Comment: @Barmar  I've used MyISAM to do so for composite autoincrementing PKs, and then used the application to handle, but I would rather not.

Comment: @sumit  A given user group is responsible for each type, and I want them to have their own incrementing series.

Comment: @AC  How can it be done with triggers?  What about the part about not duplicating a previously deleted sub-sequence ID?

Comment: I don't believe the other question addresses not reusing deleted sub-incrementing keys.

Comment: If your sequence my have gaps, then why don't you just use one sequence for all types?

Comment: OP is right - The linked answer doesn't address the requirement for not reusing a number from a deleted row. So i've voted for reopening.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  Thanks for voting to reopen.  The reason I don't want one sequence for all types is doing gives other users knowledge about another user's sequences, and also does not seem as personal.

Comment: Create a table that will store last AI numbers per type. Use a trigger to increment it on every insert and copy to the original table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  Thanks Paul,  Yeah, that should work.  Now, how to implement it...

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  Actually, it will not work.  MySQL doesn't allow to actions on the same table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330198/trigger-to-update-and-select-on-same-table-error-1235-42000 for why it will not work.

Comment: @user1032531 I have [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42333142/5563083) your question.