# Trigger to UPDATE and SELECT on same table - ERROR 1235 (42000)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to implement [Table with multiple incrementing columns which doesn't reuse deleted column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306550/table-with-multiple-incrementing-columns-which-doesnt-reuse-deleted-column-valu).  This post was tagged as already being answered by [How auto-increment within a subset of the table MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879104/how-auto-increment-within-a-subset-of-the-table-mysql), however, the referenced post did not meet the stated requirements as it allows the subset incremented keys to be duplicated. In the first post, a comment was given:

> Create a table that will store last AI numbers per type. Use a trigger
>   to increment it on every insert and copy to the original table. – Paul
>   Spiegel

I thought this was a great idea, and implemented it.

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 02/19/17 08:53:34
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t1` (
  `pk1` INT NOT NULL,
  `pk2` INT NOT NULL,
  `id2` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk1`, `pk2`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t2` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id2` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
USE `mydb`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `t2_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `t2` FOR EACH ROW
begin
UPDATE t1 SET id2=id2+1 WHERE pk1=NEW.pk1 AND pk2=NEW.pk2;
SET NEW.id2=(SELECT id2 FROM t1 WHERE pk1=NEW.pk1 AND pk2=NEW.pk2);
end$$


DELIMITER ;
```

When executing the script, however, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR 1235 (42000) at line 68: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

I am using MySQL 5.5.54.  Are there new versions which can do so?

Are there any workarounds to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably defined two BEFORE INSERT triggers on one table. At least that's what the error message says. Uncomment the second trigger in [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfa099) and you will get the same error message

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers
with the same action time and event for one table'
```

The second mistake is that you have defined the trigger on the wrong table (or you have mixed up the tables in the trigger). Your trigger is on `t2`, but you are trying to acces columns from `t1` (`NEW.pk1`). So you would get the following error message:

```
Unknown column 'pk1' in 'NEW'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1515abb (Uncomment the lines in the trigger.)

However - even fixing that, the logic doesn't look correct. A working version of what you might have intended could be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `pk1` INT NOT NULL,
  `pk2` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk1`, `pk2`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `pk1` INT NOT NULL,
  `last_pk2` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk1`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `t1_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `t1` FOR EACH ROW
begin
  UPDATE t2 SET last_pk2=last_pk2 + 1 WHERE pk1=NEW.pk1;
  SET NEW.pk2=(SELECT last_pk2 FROM t2 WHERE pk1=NEW.pk1);
end//

DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see in the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e499e7/1), the second insert doesn't specify `pk2`, but it is increased in the result.

This however will fail, if you insert a `pk1` value that is not registered in  `t2`. (Uncomment last line in the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24a170)) In this case a new row has to be inserted into `t2`. Since `pk1` is PRIMARY KEY in `t2` we can use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..` syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t1_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `t1` FOR EACH ROW
begin
  INSERT INTO t2 (pk1, last_pk2) values (NEW.pk1, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_pk2 = last_pk2 + 1;
  SET NEW.pk2=(SELECT last_pk2 FROM t2 WHERE pk1=NEW.pk1);
end//
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79eeea/1

Now last step is to make it concurrency save. We must prevent two concurrent threads/sessions to read the same value for `t2.last_pk2`. Thus writing and reading should be done in one statement. We can use a session variable or `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to do that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t1_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `t1` FOR EACH ROW
begin
  INSERT INTO t2 (pk1, last_pk2) values (NEW.pk1, @last_pk2 := 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_pk2 = @last_pk2 := (last_pk2 + 1);
  SET NEW.pk2 = @last_pk2;
end//
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc235a/1

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t1_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `t1` FOR EACH ROW
begin
  INSERT INTO t2 (pk1, last_pk2) values (NEW.pk1, LAST_INSERT_ID(1))
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_pk2 = LAST_INSERT_ID(last_pk2 + 1);
  SET NEW.pk2 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
end//
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86ed740/1